# CSS ::after bottom border animation on page load instead of hover

Tags: css, css-animations

I'd like to have this hover animation run once when the page loads, preferably without JS.Border must remain there after the animation.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
       
<style>
    .border-bottom-animate:after {
        content: "";  
        display: block; 
        width: 0%; 
         border-bottom: 5px dotted black; 
        transition: .5s;  
    }
    
    .border-bottom-animate:hover:after {
        width: 100%; 
    }
</style>
    </head>
<body>

    <div class="container border-bottom-animate">
        <p style="font-size: xx-large">
            I want to animate this without hover
        </p>
        
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-IDwe1+LCz02ROU9k972gdyvl+AESN10+x7tBKgc9I5HFtuNz0wWnPclzo6p9vxnk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

That is all there is to the problem. No further details worthy of adding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
       
<style>
    .border-bottom-animate:after {
         content: "";  
         display: block; 
         border-bottom: 5px dotted black; 
         transition: .5s;  
         width: 100%;
         animation-duration: 3s;
         animation-name: border-animation;
    }

    @keyframes border-animation {
      from {
         width: 0%;
      }
      to {
        width: 100%;
      }
   } 
</style>
    </head>
<body>

    <div class="container border-bottom-animate">
        <p style="font-size: xx-large">
            I want to animate this without hover
        </p>
        
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-IDwe1+LCz02ROU9k972gdyvl+AESN10+x7tBKgc9I5HFtuNz0wWnPclzo6p9vxnk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I should add that the border must remain there after the animation.

Comment: width: 0px;  => width: 100%;

Comment: Works great. Wanna just edit that and i'll accept your answer?

Comment: You also don't need the 'transition: .5s;' anymore